# laravel autoload classmap class not found

Tags: laravel, autoload

I have some helpers in my factories directory (`database\factories\FactoryHelpers.php`)

```
<?php

class FactoryHelpers
{ 
...
}
```

Now I try to use it in my tests, and get `class FactoryHelpers not found`

I thought that putting

```
"classmap": [
            "database/factories"
        ],
```

In my composer file should be enough to make the FactoryHelpers class available globally.

EDIT:

composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0.0",
        "barryvdh/laravel-cors": "^0.9.3",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "webpatser/laravel-uuid": "^3.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "v2.4.1",
        "codeception/codeception": "^2.3",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.6",
        "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "krlove/eloquent-model-generator": "^1.2",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "mpociot/laravel-test-factory-helper": "^0.5.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you generated a new autoload file with `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: @mrHooty Thanks, that worked. However I now get name already in use. The file seems to get loaded twice. I can fix it with if (!class_exists('FactoryHelpers')) { ... but I am wondering why it is loaded multiple times

Comment: Please attach your full composer.json. In Laravel 5.5 for example, it is loading these by default.

Comment: @mrHooty done :)